# Automating IHTMLElement OnKeyUp event with RAD Studio

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, dom, automation, c++builder

I am trying to fire an OnKeyUp event within the code I have outlined below. The OnKeyUp event will therefore trigger some javascript within the HTML of the page I am trying to automate.

I am working on a project that automates IE using RAD Studio XE6 C++.  I have an element that requires an **OnKeyUp** event to be fired. But it does not trigger the javascript.

The HTML code that I want to automate is:

```html
<input
   name="tbSearch"
   type="text"
   value="ZZZ"
   maxlength="10"
   id="tbSearch"
   class="smltxtbox txtlabel"
   ContentEditable="true"
   unselectable="off"
   OnBlur="Lookup(tbSearch,&#39;TC&#39;)"
   OnKeyUp="KeyUp(tbSearch, this)"
/>
```

The code I am using so far is ...

```cpp
bool __fastcall SessionData::UpdateValueByIDTest(String id,String value) 
{
    IHTMLDocument3* htmldoc3;
    tagVARIANT keyup;
    HRESULT hresult;
    if (SUCCEEDED(ie->Document->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument3,(void**)&htmldoc3))) 
    {
        IHTMLElement* htmlElement;
        htmldoc3->getElementById(WideString(id).c_bstr(), &htmlElement);
        if (htmlElement)
        {
            //the value is updated OK
            htmlElement>setAttribute(WideString("value").c_bstr(),TVariant(value));
            hresult=htmlElement->get_onkeyup(&keyup);
            //expecting this to fire the OnKeyUp event, but it does not.
            hresult=htmlElement->put_onkeypress(keyup);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?  Is something now working?

Comment: I am mot sure what you mean here? I have just posted my first question on stackoverflow and waiting for some response.

Comment: Please clarify what it is you want help with.  So far you have not written an actual question, you just wrote a bunch of facts.  Where is the actual question?  What do you want help doing?  You need to be a lot more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply re-assigning the existing `OnKeyUp` event handler back to the `OnKeyUp` event.  You are not actually firing the event at all.

Prior to IE11, use the element's [`IHTMLElement3::fireEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/aa703947) method.

In IE11 and later, you need to use the [`IEventTarget::dispatchEvent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ff975826) method instead.

Try something like this:

```cpp
#include <utilcls.h>

bool __fastcall SessionData::UpdateValueByIDTest(String id,String value) 
{
    TComInterface<IHTMLDocument3> htmldoc3 = ie->Document;
    if (htmldoc3)
    {
        TComInterface<IHTMLElement> htmlElement;
        if (SUCCEEDED(htmldoc3->getElementById(WideString(id).c_bstr(), &htmlElement)))
        {
            htmlElement->setAttribute(WideString(L"value").c_bstr(), TVariant(value));

            //fire the OnKeyUp event

            TComInterface<IDocumentEvent> documentEvent = htmldoc3;
            TComInterface<IEventTarget> eventTarget = htmlElement;

            if ((documentEvent) && (eventTarget))
            {
                TComInterface<IDOMEvent> eventObj;
                if (SUCCEEDED(documentEvent->createEvent(WideString(L"KeyboardEvent").c_bstr(), &eventObj)))
                {
                    TComInterface<IDOMKeyboardEvent> keybdEvent = eventObj;
                    keybdEvent->initKeyboardEvent(WideString(L"keyup").c_bstr(), VARIANT_TRUE, VARIANT_TRUE, NULL, WideString(L"<desired key>").c_bstr, DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD, WideString(L"<desired modifiers>").c_str(), VARIANT_FALSE, WideString(L"en-US").c_str());
                    // set other event properties as needed...

                    VARIANT_BOOL bPreventDefault = VARIANT_FALSE;
                    eventTarget->dispatchEvent(eventObj, &bPreventDefault);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TComInterface<IHTMLDocument4> htmldoc4 = ie->Document;
                TComInterface<IHTMLElement3> htmlElement3 = htmlElement;
                if (htmldoc4 && htmlElement3)
                {
                    TVariant empty;
                    TComInterface<IHTMLEventObj> eventObj;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(htmldoc4->createEventObject(&empty, &eventObj)))
                    {
                        eventObj->put_keyCode(<desired key>);
                        // set other event properties as needed...

                        VARIANT_BOOL bCancelled = VARIANT_FALSE;
                        htmlElement3->fireEvent(WideString(L"onkeyup").c_bstr(), TVariant(eventObj), &bCancelled);
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```